# Is there a way to filter by an annotation field where the Count is 0?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Here is the example I am referring to:

```
all_hats = Hats.objects.all()
issues=[]
issues_to_match = [issue.id for issue in issues]
matching_issues_count = Count("issues", filter=Q(issues__id__in=issues_to_match))
qs = all_hats.annotate(matching_issues_count=matching_issues_count)
qs.filter(matching_issues_count=0)
```

So if in this case issues is an empty list, when you print `qs.matching_issues_count` you get `0`. So when you `qs.filter(matching_issues_count=0)` you should get that result no?
In reality you return an empty queryset.

Furthermore, `print(qs.filter(matching_issues_count=0).query)` returns an `EmptyResultSet` `ValidationError`

Any information on this or do I have to structure the query another way? Or add a condition for when issues is empty? Thanks.

Comment: Your `issues_to_match` is an empty list... Since `issues` is an empty list, it does not matter if you fetch the `.id` or any other attribute, it will *never* be evaluated, since `issues` is empty. The queryset raises an error, since `__in=empty_list` will never satisfy the predicate.

Comment: So you can never filter by this count in that case? I just felt it strange as the annotated field still returns 0 `qs.matching_issues_count=0`. If it's true that this can never be done, what is the alternative? Is the error in this Q object? `filter=Q(issues__id__in=issues_to_match)`